# Home networking with an access point and switch?

Tags: home-networking

I am currently wanting to update my home networking system. I want something like this diagram.

```
ISP data cable --> Switch --> Access point
```

Our current setup is like this:

```
ISP data cable --> Router
```

Anything I need to know before attempting this?

Comment: Where is your "ISP data cable" coming from? Do you have an ISP provided modem? Why change the router configuration you already have? You can increase your network by simply plugging the switch into the routet's LAN socket. Same goes for the AP...

Answer (score 2):

In most ISP setup scenarios this won't work (there are exceptions).

A router provides the "demarcation" of services to you from your provider - thus any resources would need to be provisioned to/through the router.

If you start running a LAN directly on that network you will normally not have the appropriate IP address space and routing set up.  In the unlikely event you can make it work you are also going to decrease the performance of your network.

You may want to change you setup to

ISP Cable -> Router -> Switch -> Access Point   - This is entirely acceptable as the switch and access point operate at a "lower level", and are not visible to the router.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few items to take into account.  I will assume that the ISP data cable is Ethernet unless you specify otherwise.  Further you need to know if the ISP is providing you with one public IP that you would then need to Network Address Translate (NAT).  That is the job of the router, which converts the public IP to a private IP range (ex 192.168.1.1->192.168.1.255).  In this case perhaps your access point (AP) can also perform that job, which is fairly common.

All of your potential problems will arise from NAT,   Many times NAT is a one way port.  So your AP takes a public IP thru its ethernet port and will NAT it to a private range on the wireless signal ONLY. That does not mean that a computer plugged into the switch will be able to gain access to the NAT provided by the AP TO the wireless devices.  This assumes that the AP has only ONE Ethernet port.  If it has multiple, then the AP has a router built in.

As you have provided very little information, it is possible that you only need the ONE public IP address and don't care about NAT at all because you only have ONE host/device connecting.

The only problem you may face depending on the equipment is if you need a crossover cable or not.  Some switches will detect and crossover automatically (auto-MDIX).  If you get a link light, then you can ignore this potential problem as your switch already handled it.

Good Luck.  The devil is in the details on networking.  If you provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish I would be happy to assist.